# Read Unix executable file programmatically using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

If I have a text file in the "Resources" folder, I can do something like this to read the file into a string:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" 
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
```

Some modifications in the code could also read unicode(rtf) files, but I have an Unix Executable file which doesn't have any extension.

I want to do something like the above to read this file too.

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Do you simply want to read the file into a buffer or do you want to read the executable headers etc?

Comment: @Droppy I just want to read the file by placing entire content in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read an executable file into a string, as it contains binary data, so you should store its contents within an `NSData` object.

Reading it is trivial:

```
NSString *exeFilePath = ...;  // Whatever
NSData *exeFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:exeFilePath];
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this out.
As I am developing an iphone app, could you also suggest as where should I place the file?
I mean directly in the Resources folder or somewhere else

Comment: @Sibir What is the executable file?  If it's something you supply then it should be within the Resources folder yes, however if you intend to add your app to the app store then I think Apple would reject it if the app bundle contained an executable file; I'm not certain however.